# Jquery plugins for an image viewer

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Does any one know of any plugin i can use for an image viewer like this
http://www.rightmove.co.uk/student-accommodation/property-13062309.html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try jCarousel
http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

Answer (score 0):

Yes just tried the carousel above, excellent and so professional looking too,  http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel
If you wish to simulate the exact viewer used on rightmove, (OMG I can see that the question was posted 2011 LOL) this is the one from:
pikachoose-96   (google search should find it)

you will need to modify the css slightly in styles/bottom.css
so that the thumbs are underneath the main large gallery image,

then having stored all your images in a php array which looks for all .jpg files only,
add a line like this below
so that the fancy lightbox (enlarge mode) can be accessed:

(HOPE THE PHP CODE SHOWS UP IN THIS MESSAGE for you)